# Best way to unselect a <select> in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, select

```
<select size="2">
<option selected="selected">Input your option</option>
<option>Input your option</option>
</select>
```

What is the best way, using jQuery, to elegantly unselect the  option?

Answer (score 395, accepted):

Use [removeAttr](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/removeAttr)...

```
$("option:selected").removeAttr("selected");
```

Or [Prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop)

```
$("option:selected").prop("selected", false)
```

Comment: Does not work under IE 8.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7960773/jquery-remove-selected-attribute-of-option#

Comment: This answer is not the way to do things (and doesn't work universally to boot). The correct approaches are either `.val([])` or `.prop("selected", false)` -- scroll down.

Comment: JQuery must've fixed this, It's working perfect for me in IE8 using JQuery 1.7.2.

Comment: can also set `.prop('selectedIndex', 0 /* or -1 */)`. This is the native javascript api. If you set it to 0, it will select the first option. Works well if you have a default option like in the OP's case. If you set it to -1 it will have no option selected and just be blank.

Comment: OR .val(['']) to select the empty value if any.

Comment: `$("option:selected").prop("selected", false)` sometimes not working. (not working in chrome browser with jquery v1.4.2)

Comment: $('#theSelectElemId option:selected').removeProp('selected');

Comment: At this time `prop` is the correct answer (for Chrome).
`prop` deselects while `removeAttr` removes the default "selected" and does not deselect.

Comment: `$("option:selected").removeAttr("selected");` does not work for me on Firefox 66 on Linux Fedora, while `$("option:selected").prop("selected", false)` works

Comment: 2019 with Chrome 76. Only one that works is the `.removeAttr("selected")`. I'm on IOS also.

Comment: it's better to point to the in-mind selectList first
$("#selectList").find('option:selected').removeAttr("selected");

Answer (score 190):

There are lots of answers here but unfortunately all of them are quite old and therefore rely on `attr`/`removeAttr` which is really not the way to go.

@coffeeyesplease correctly mentions that a good, cross-browser solution is to use

```
$("select").val([]);
```

Another good cross-browser solution is

```
// Note the use of .prop instead of .attr
$("select option").prop("selected", false);
```

You can see it run a self-test [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jS3ws/). Tested on IE 7/8/9, FF 11, Chrome 19.

Comment: Much better than the select answer, (works cross browser and doesn't involve messing with the attribute sets)

Comment: Perfect answer for unselecting *all* options.  But it can't really be used to unselect specific options, whereas removeAttr can.

Comment: @MikeyG: Sure it can. `.val()`, remove the specific options and `.val(remaining)`. :-)

Comment: hmmm... i'm having problems getting that working.  I'm sure i'm just doing something wrong.  So you're saying something like this: `$("select").children("option.test").val([])` ?

Comment: @MikeyG: [This](http://jsfiddle.net/aWbD8/1), noting that [`Array.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) needs a polyfill for IE < 9 (or you can use any equivalent method that many JS libraries provide).

Comment: Did you check the HTML after `$('#select').val([]);`? Unfortunately, this doesn't remove `selected="selected"` attribute. That may end up posting wrong data. I do not recommend this approach!

Comment: @Fr0zenFyr: If you start with a preselected option and you unselect it manually with a mouse click, that doesn't remove the attribute either -- and yet of course submitting the form is guaranteed to post correct data. There is a world of difference between the HTML *attributes* (that determine initial state) and the DOM *properties* (that determine what displays and what gets submitted). This is in fact the reason why solutions focusing on the attribute are incorrect. The attribute determines the initial value of the property, but that's as far as it goes.

Comment: Understood and agreed! I take back my statement about not recommending this approach(can't edit the previous comment, though). By the way, when I tried `val([""])` why doesn't it select the option at 0 index? Is there a way to select very first option (i.e "Select <something>") with `.val([])` ?

Comment: My bad, i typed `.val([0])`. both `.val('')` and `.val([''])` should work for select box. Thanks. Which approach is preferred and fail safe, `.val([])` or `.prop()`

Comment: @Fr0zenFyr: Both are fully correct, I guess `val` is more convenient because it targets the dropdown instead of the `<option>` elements.

Comment: `$("select").val([]);` only works on a multi-select w/ new versions of Jquery. `$("select option").prop("selected", false);` seems to work for both single and multi-selects so is a better answer IMO.

Comment: Simple and to the point. However, if you want to show a default value instead of an empty menu, use `$("select").val("");`

Answer (score 34):

### Simplest Method

#### `$('select').val('')`

I simply used this on the select itself and it did the trick.

I'm on **jQuery 1.7.1**.

Comment: I just faced with one problem about this solution. Option tag will still have attribute "selected"

Comment: @Tamara Really? I didn't check. Are you using "selected" for something and this messes things up for you?

Comment: I think you have to add .trigger('change') so $('select').val('').trigger('change');

Answer (score 26):

It's a been a while since asked, and I haven't tested this on older browsers but it seems to me a much simpler answer is

```
$("#selectID").val([]);
```

.val() works for select as well http://api.jquery.com/val/

Comment: This is the best way and actually clears the value in most browsers - thanks.

Comment: This only works for multi-selects.  `$("select option").prop("selected", false);` works universally (on multi and single selects).

Comment: For me, this works as expected for single selects in IE11 and Chrome using jQuery 3.6.0.

Answer (score 19):

Answers so far only work for multiple selects in IE6/7; for the more common non-multi select,  you need to use:

```
$("#selectID").attr('selectedIndex', '-1');
```

This is explained in the post linked by flyfishr64.  If you look at it, you will see how there are 2 cases - multi / non-multi.  There is nothing stopping you chaning both for a complete solution:

```
$("#selectID").attr('selectedIndex', '-1').find("option:selected").removeAttr("selected");
```

Answer (score 13):

Oh jquery.

Since there is yet a native javascript approach, I feel the need to provide one.

```
var select = document.querySelector('select'); //hopefully you'll use a better selector query
select.selectedIndex = 0; // or -1, 0 sets it to first option, -1 selects no options
```

And just to show you how much faster this is: [benchmark](http://jsperf.com/deselect-select)

Comment: Thank for this answer without jQuery ! :)

Answer (score 7):

```
$("#selectID option:selected").each(function(){
  $(this).removeAttr("selected");
});
```

This would iterate through each item and unselect only the ones which are checked

Answer (score 6):

A quick google found [this post](http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-en/browse_thread/thread/af73f2b57473ffb6) that describes how to do what you want for both single and multiple select lists in IE. The solution seems pretty elegant as well:

```
$('#clickme').click(function() {
        $('#selectmenu option').attr('selected', false);

});
```

Answer (score 6):

```
$("#select_id option:selected").prop("selected", false);
```

Answer (score 4):

Another simple way:

`$("#selectedID")[0].selectedIndex = -1`

Answer (score 3):

```
$(option).removeAttr('selected') //replace 'option' with selected option's selector
```

Answer (score 3):

Thanks a lot for the solution.

The solution for single choice combo list works perfectly. I found this after searching on many sites.

```
$("#selectID").attr('selectedIndex', '-1').children("option:selected").removeAttr("selected");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("option:selected").attr("selected", false);
```

Answer (score 2):

This code works for me.

```
$("option:selected").prop("selected", false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually when I use a select menu, each option has a value associated with it.
For example

```
<select id="nfl">
  <option value="Bears Still...">Chicago Bears</option>
  <option selected="selected" value="Go Pack">Green Bay Packers</option>
</select>
console.log($('#nfl').val()) logs "Go Pack" to the console
Set the value to an empty string $('#nfl').val("")
console.log($('#nfl').val()) logs "" to the console
```

Now this doesn't remove the selected attribute from the option but all I really want is the value.

Answer (score 0):

Set a id in your select, like:
`<select id="foo" size="2">`

Then you can use:
`$("#foo").prop("selectedIndex", 0).change();`

Answer (score 0):

To unselect an option in an  element using jQuery, you can simply set the selectedIndex property of the  element to -1. This will remove any selected option and leave the dropdown empty.

Here's how you can do it:

```
<select id="mySelect">
  <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
</select>

// Using jQuery to unselect the <select> element
$("#mySelect").prop("selectedIndex", -1);
```

In this example, the  element with the ID "mySelect" will have its selected option removed when the jQuery code is executed.

Note: Setting selectedIndex to -1 effectively unselects all options, but it won't trigger any "change" event on the  element. If you need to handle any behaviour when the selection changes, you may need to trigger the event manually after unselecting the option:

```
$("#mySelect").prop("selectedIndex", -1).trigger("change");
```