# Remove an element from dropdownlist helper

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a view that contains two `@Html.DropDownListFor` helpers:

```
 <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Employee, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.emps, "--Select--", new { style = "width:150px", id = "ddl1"})
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Employee)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Employee2, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.emps, "--Select--", new { style = "width:150px", id = "ddl2"})
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Employee2)
    </div>
```

They are populated like this:

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {
        List<Employees> emps = new List<Employees>();
        emps.Add(new Employees { Id = 0, Name = "Michael Jordan" });
        emps.Add(new Employees { Id = 1, Name = "Magic Johnson" });
        emps.Add(new Employees { Id = 2, Name = "Larry Bird" });

        var items = emps.Select(i => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value= i.Id.ToString(),
            Text =i.Name
        });
        ViewBag.emps = items;
        return View();
    }
```

How can I remove the selected item of the first DDL from the second DDL?
I managed to get the selected item using jQuery like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#ddl1").change(function () {
        alert($("#ddl1").val());
    });
});
</script>
```

However, I couldn't find a way to use it for my purpose.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove the selected element during a clone() operation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2882470/how-to-remove-the-selected-element-during-a-clone-operation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this must work for you:

```
$(function(){
    var lists = $('#ddl1, #ddl2');
    lists.change(function(){
        var elm = $(this);
        lists.find('option').show();
        var option = lists.not('#' + this.id)
            .find('option[value="' + elm.val() +'"]').hide();

        if(option.is(':selected'))
        {
            var select = option.closest('select');
            select.val(select.find('option:visible:first').val());
        }
    });
});
```

Link for demo: [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/cxZ2H/)

**Added:**
Posted solution have problems with IE, alternative way is use disabled attribute: [jsfiddle.net/cxZ2H/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/cxZ2H/1/)

Comment: works great in firefox but not in IE. any way to make it work in internet explorer?

Comment: @Yoav Yes, it is my fault, IE do not allow `display:none` for option ([proof](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324250/style-display-none-doesnt-work-on-option-tags-in-chrome-but-it-does-in-firefo) ). Alternative solution use disable, if this solution is ok? Here is link: [jsfiddle.net/cxZ2H/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/cxZ2H/1/)

Answer (score 2):

This is definitely a client-side scripting problem as opposed to a server-side ASP.NET MVC problem.

Here is my advice:

1. Create your item list server-side.
2. But when you bring it to the client, keep an immutable master copy. Use it to populate your first `select`.
3. When the user selects an item from the first list, make a clone of the first list, minus the selected item.

Here's a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Fsf7g/1/