# Clone div and remove class without changing the original one

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I want to clone the content of the div using jQuery, but from the copied content I want to remove the class from the original one before I use appendTo function. When I remove the class from a clone they also remove from the original one.

My code is:

```
$('.carousel .item').each(function(){
        var next = $(this).next();

        if (!next.length) {
            next = $(this).siblings(':first');
        }
        next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
        next.children(':first-child').addClass('col-sm-offset-1');

        for (var i=0;i<3;i++) {
            next=next.next();
            if (!next.length) {
                next = $(this).siblings(':first');
            }
            next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));                 
        }

});
```

Please note, I don't want to remove class from actual div from where I copied the content, I just want to remove it from the copied code so that it is not included in the cloned div.

Comment: i don't see code to remove class , can you update your code with remove class , where are you trying to remove class

Comment: next.children(':first-child').removeClass('col-sm-offset-1').clone().appendTo($(this));  //here i remove the clone div class

Answer (score 5):

You can use  `removeClass` and `addClass` after `clone` like this.

```
 .clone().removeClass('oldClass').addClass('col-sm-offset-1')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove element from cloned object first and then clone to your new object which would be something like shown below:

```
$('.carousel .item').each(function(){ var next = $(this).next();    
        if (!next.length) {
            next = $(this).siblings(':first');
        }
        var $block = next.children(':first-child');

        // Grab the and remove element class
        $block = $block.find('.your-element-identity-class').removeClass('your-element-identity-class');

        // Clone the block 
        var $clone = $block.clone();

        $clone.appendTo($(this));
        next.children(':first-child').addClass('col-sm-offset-1');

        for (var i=0;i<3;i++) {
            next=next.next();
            if (!next.length) {
                next = $(this).siblings(':first');
            }
            var $block = next.children(':first-child');

            // Grab the and remove element class
            $block = $block.find('.your-element-identity-class').removeClass('your-element-identity-class');

            // Clone the block 
            var $clone = $block.clone();

            $clone.appendTo($(this));                
        }

    });
```

Replace "your-element-identity-class" with your class name you want to remove.
Original ref. from - [How to remove the selected element during a clone() operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2882470/how-to-remove-the-selected-element-during-a-clone-operation)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to run [removeClass()](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) on the object before you append it, regardless of where you want to append it to.

Comment: next.children(':first-child').removeClass('col-sm-offset-1')‌​.clone().appendTo($(‌​this));  i use this but its remopve from original div also