# dropdown not working when clicked a second time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem with my checkbox. If I select a value and validate, I can't do that a second time, it's not working. Looking at other questions, I saw that I may have to use the prop() function with the "checked" property, which I did, but it's still not working.

Here is my website : http://nts.nuvision.co.za/index.php/training/

Here is my javascript :

```
    $('#one').hide();
    $('#two').hide();
    $('#three').hide();
    $('#show').click(function() {
        $('#pgc-224-0-1').css("margin-top", "0px");
        switch(document.getElementById('trainingcourses').value) {
            case 'one':
                $('#one').show();
                $('#two').hide();
                $('#three').hide();
                $("#trainingcourses").prop('checked', false);

            break;
            case 'two':
                $('#two').show();
                $('#one').hide();
                $('#three').hide();
                $("#trainingcourses").prop('checked', false);

            break;
            case 'three':
                $('#three').show();
                $('#two').hide();
                $('#one').hide();
                $("#trainingcourses").prop('checked', false);

            break;
        }
    });
```

And here my HTML :

```
<form id="trainingform">
<select id="trainingcourses" style="font-size: 12pt;">
<option style="font-size: 12pt;" value="one">Sugar and Suite CRM End User Training</option>
<option style="font-size: 12pt;" value="two">Sugar & Suite CRM Advanced End User Training</option>
<option style="font-size: 12pt;" value="three">Sugar and Suite CRM Administrator : Getting Started</option>
</select><input id="show" style="margin-top: -25px; margin-left: 20px;" name="show" type="submit" value="Show more information" onclick="location.href='http://nts.nuvision.co.za/index.php/training/#' + document.getElementById('trainingcourses').value; return false;"/></form>

<div id="one"> (...) </div>
<div id="two"> (...) </div>
<div id="three"> (...) </div>
```

Comment: Checkbox or dropdown?...please make your question clearer..

Comment: dropdown my mistake, sorry

Comment: thanks for the link, but I actually saw it when I was doing some research, it didn't work for me

Comment: for dropdown
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7960773/jquery-remove-selected-attribute-of-option

Comment: it works thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `checked` property to select box which is not valid. remove below lines from your switch case statement and it should work.

```
$("#trainingcourses").prop('checked', false);
```

Also not sure if you need a submit button here or not. If you need simple button which should not submit the page then change show button `type="submit"` to `type="button"`.