# How to select and unselect buttons in this situation

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, button, drop-down-menu

I included a jQuery handler for my dropdown menus so that when something is selected in the first dropdown menu, it will manipulate the options in the second dropdown menu. Now what the user does is pick the option type in the first dropdown (`OptionDropId`) menu and then in the second dropdown (`NumberDropId`) menu the user selects the number of answers wanted. Below that dropdown menu a list of buttons would appear and the user selects the number of buttons depending on how many the user has selected in the second dropdown menu.

Now let's say user clicks on two buttons and then changes the option type (first dropdown menu), then the buttons selected are still selected, I want the buttons to be unselected if the option type has changed.

This used to work but since I have included my `change` event handler to bind my jquery (this code is needed), it does not unselect buttons when the option type changes.

What do I need to do to fix this:

Below is my jquery and function of select and unselect buttons:

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    var OptDrop = new Array();

    OptDrop.abc = ["",1,2];
    OptDrop.abcd = ["",1,2,3];
    OptDrop.abcde = ["",1,2,3,4];
    OptDrop.trueorfalse = [1];
    OptDrop.yesorno = [1];

    $("#optionDropId").change(function ()
    {
        var selectedValue = $(this).val();
        $("#numberDropId").html("");
        $.each(OptDrop[selectedValue], function (x, y)
        {
            $("#numberDropId").append($("<option></option>").attr("value", y).html(y));
        });
    }); 

    $("#optionDropId").change();
});       

var currenttotal=0;
function getButtons()
{
    document.getElementById("answerA").className="answerBtnsOff";
    document.getElementById("answerB").className="answerBtnsOff";
    document.getElementById("answerC").className="answerBtnsOff";
    document.getElementById("answerD").className="answerBtnsOff";
    document.getElementById("answerE").className="answerBtnsOff";       
    document.getElementById("answerTrue").className="answerBtnsOff";
    document.getElementById("answerFalse").className="answerBtnsOff";
    document.getElementById("answerYes").className="answerBtnsOff";
    document.getElementById("answerNo").className="answerBtnsOff";

    currenttotal=0;
}

function btnclick(btn)
{
    if(document.getElementById("numberDropId").value=="")
    {
        alert('You must first select the number of answers you require from the drop down menu');
        return false;
    }
    if (btn.className=="answerBtnsOn")
    {
        btn.className="answerBtnsOff";
        currenttotal--;
        return false;
    }
    if(document.getElementById("numberDropId").value==currenttotal)
    {
        alert('You are not allowed beyond the limit of the number of answers you require, deselect other button');
        return false;
    }
    if (btn.className=="answerBtnsOff")
    {
        btn.className="answerBtnsOn";
        currenttotal++;
        return false;
    }

}
```

Html code is below:

```
<form id="enter" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm(this);">
  <table id="optionAndAnswer">
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">
        Option and Answer
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Option Type:</td> 
      <td>
        <select name="optionDrop" id="optionDropId" onChange="getDropDown()">
          <option value="">Please Select</option>
          <option value="abc">ABC</option>
          <option value="abcd">ABCD</option>
          <option value="abcde">ABCDE</option>
          <option value="trueorfalse">True or False</option>
          <option value="yesorno">Yes or No</option>
        </select>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>Number of Answers:</td>
     <td>
       <select name="numberDrop" id="numberDropId" onChange="getButtons()">
       </select>
     </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>Answer</td>
     <td>
       <input class="answerBtns" name="answerAName" id="answerA" type="button" value="A" onclick="javascript:btnclick(this);"/>
       <input class="answerBtns" name="answerBName" id="answerB" type="button"   value="B" onclick="javascript:btnclick(this);"/>
       <input class="answerBtns" name="answerCName" id="answerC" type="button"   value="C" onclick="javascript:btnclick(this);"/>
       <input class="answerBtns" name="answerDName" id="answerD" type="button"      value="D" onclick="javascript:btnclick(this);"/>
       <input class="answerBtns" name="answerEName" id="answerE" type="button"   value="E" onclick="javascript:btnclick(this);"/>
       <input class="answerBtns" name="answerTrueName" id="answerTrue" type="button"    value="True" onclick="javascript:btnclick(this);"/>
       <input class="answerBtns" name="answerFalseName" id="answerFalse" type="button"   value="False" onclick="javascript:btnclick(this);"/>
       <input class="answerBtns" name="answerYesName" id="answerYes" type="button"   value="Yes" onclick="javascript:btnclick(this);"/>
       <input class="answerBtns" name="answerNoName" id="answerNo"      type="button" value="No" onclick="javascript:btnclick(this);"/>
     </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use Jquery's .removeAtrr() function as described here: [Best way to unselect a <select> in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1857781/best-way-to-unselect-a-select-in-jquery)

Then your change function would look like this:

```
$("#optionDropId").change(function ()
    {
        var selectedValue = $(this).val();
        $("#numberDropId").html("");
        $.each(OptDrop[selectedValue], function (x, y)
        {
            $("#numberDropId").append($("<option></option>").attr("value", y).html(y));
        });
        $("#numberDropId").removeAttr("selected");
    });
```

Comment: It would, probably, be better to use [`prop('selected',false)`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) to unselect a selected `option`, as the `selected` (and `checked`, for `radio` and `checkbox` type inputs) is a property, rather than an attribute.

Comment: Hi, I tried using the removeAttr() and prop() methods but they both did not work, still same problem, I tried using numberDropId but because the issue is OptionDropId as when that dropdown option changes the buttons do not unselect but that still did not work