# How to reset a select element with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have

```
<select id="baba">
<option>select something</option>
<option value="1">something 1</option>
<option value=2">something 2</option>
</select>
```

Using jQuery, what would be the easiest (less to write) way to reset the `select` so the first option is selected?

Comment: When do you want this reset to happen? if on page load, simply add attribute selected to that option.

Comment: @Vega it is not relevant to the question when I want this to happen. It is hooked to an event triggered by a user action.

Answer (score 212, accepted):

Try this. This will work. `$('#baba').prop('selectedIndex',0);`

Check here http://jsfiddle.net/bibin_v/R4s3U/

Comment: If i understood correctly, then he wants to select `<option>select something</option>`

Comment: This does not trigger the `change` event

Comment: This has one downside: it will select the first element of a <select multiple>. https://stackoverflow.com/a/20655843/1405981 is a better answer.

Answer (score 35):

In your case (and in most use cases I have seen), all you need is:

```
$("#baba").val("");
```

[**Demo**.](http://jsfiddle.net/gYR4a/)

Comment: if the select element does not have an option with `value=""` then one will be created in newer versions of jquery

Comment: I stumbled upon the exact issue. My code suddenly stopped working and I figured out that upgrading jquery from 1x to 2x was the reason. Hence it is dangerous to use this code. One small correction to @billynoah 's comment - A new option tag won't be created, but the selected value will be null. On clicking the select, we will be able to select from the original list of options only. Better use some other solution as it will fail in jquery 2+.

Comment: Down voting. This does not work with newer versions of jquery and has a bad side-effect of creating a new option and you will have to fix this if you upgrade.

Comment: do you have any solution how to resolve this problem using .val("") to set first option in select in newer version of jquery? i cant simply replace this and use other solution, because my system is huge and this stopped working after upgrade jquery from 1.7 to 3.6

Answer (score 18):

```
$('#baba option:first').prop('selected',true);
```

Nowadays you best use **.prop()**: http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: Very helpful link - key part for me was (substitute 'checked' for 'selected' in our case):  "The checked attribute value does not change with the state of the checkbox, while the checked property does".  So attribute in this case only initializes the selection.  Using "prop' allows you to change the selection state, which as you advise is best to use.  Thank you Roko!

Comment: @JamesLee you're very welcome. Yes, `checked` is for checkboxes and radio buttons.

Comment: this is really works with the same example above, as the first option has not val

Answer (score 15):

if none of those solutions didn't work for you, try adding after

```
.trigger( "change" );
```

ex.

```
$("#baba").val("").trigger( "change" );
```

or

```
$("#baba").val(false).trigger( "change" );
```

or

```
$("#baba option").prop("selected", false).trigger( "change" );
```

or

```
$('#baba').prop('selectedIndex',-1).trigger( "change" );
```

or

```
$('#baba option:first').prop('selected',true).trigger( "change" );
```

Comment: Most comprehensive answer +1, but should give a short explanation about each option.  They vary a little.

Answer (score 9):

```
$('#baba').prop('selectedIndex',-1);
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, because it also covers a `<select multiple>`

Comment: For me it worked similar to `$('#baba').val("")`

Answer (score 7):

Reset single select field to default option.

```
<select id="name">
    <option>select something</option>
    <option value="1" >something 1</option>
    <option value="2" selected="selected" >Default option</option>
</select>
<script>
    $('name').val( $('name').find("option[selected]").val() );
</script>
```

Or if you want to reset all form fields to the default option:

```
<script>
    $('select').each( function() {
        $(this).val( $(this).find("option[selected]").val() );
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

**Edit:** Old fashioned way,

```
document.getElementById('baba').selectedIndex = 0;
```

<s>Try below and it should work for your case,</s>

```
$('#baba option:first').prop('selected', true);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/PkLpS/1/)

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#baba option:first').attr('selected',true);
```

Answer (score 2):

This function should work for all types of select (multiple, select, select2):

```
$.fn.Reset_List_To_Default_Value = function()
{
    $.each($(this), function(index, el) {
        var Founded = false;

        $(this).find('option').each(function(i, opt) {
            if(opt.defaultSelected){
                opt.selected = true;
                Founded = true;
            }
        });

        if(!Founded)
        {
            if($(this).attr('multiple'))
            {
                $(this).val([]);
            }
            else
            {
                $(this).val("");
            }
        }
        $(this).trigger('change');
    });
}
```

To use it just call:

```
$('select').Reset_List_To_Default_Value();
```

Answer (score 1):

This does the trick, and works for any select.

```
$('#baba').val($(this).find('option:first').val());
```

Answer (score 1):

The best javascript solution I've found is this

```
elm.options[0].selected="selected";
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use the first option (in case the field is hidden or something) then the following jQuery code is enough:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#but').click(function(){
        $('#baba').val(false);
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="baba">
<option>select something</option>
<option value="1">something 1</option>
<option value=2">something 2</option>
</select>
    
    <input type="button" id="but" value="click">
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe:

```
$("select option:first-child").attr("selected", "selected");
```

Answer (score 0):

This works a little differently from other answers in that it unselects all options:

```
$("#baba option").prop("selected", false);
```

(Borrowed from https://stackoverflow.com/a/11098981/1048376)

Answer (score 0):

Using `val("").trigger("change")` works well for me.

Here's an example: I want to clear the select when the modal is hidden.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#myModal").on("hidden.bs.modal", function () {
        $("#mySelect").val("").trigger("change")
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

This works for me:

```
$('#DropList option:first').prop('selected',true).trigger("change");
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Use `$("#idOfSelectElement").val(0);`
It works for me.

In your case `$("#baba").val(0);`