# Material style select with jQuery

Tags: javascript

I need to style a series of Select options for a form, and I'm looking for jQuery plugins that allow me to do this. However, I also need to be able to reset the Select box (or even just choose the first Option) when I click on an input type="reset". Does anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: You dont need jquery to style select box. You can check bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

For the select reset just see this answer:
[How to reset a select element with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10502093/how-to-reset-a-select-element-with-jquery)

For the style what do you mean?

1) Static Style;

2) Dynamic Style;

For the static styling learn something about css properties and style them with your proper `class` attribute.

```
.my-class-color {
   color: red;
   border: 2px solid black;
}
```

For the dynamic styling you need a mixing of css classes and jquery events.

```
// Add class when user change value of select
$(document).on('change', 'select.select-form', function() {
    $(this).addClass('my-class-color');
});
```