# jquery "clear" value in select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select

So I have some markup that looks like this, And some jQuery javascript:

```js
let color_select = $('select#SelectByColor');
color_select.val([]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="SelectByColor" class='filter-select' name='color'>
  <option value="">By color</option>
  <option value="Red">Red</option>
  <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
  <option value="Green" selected="selected">Green</option>
  <option value="Yellow">Yellow</option>
</select>

<button id="FilterReset">Reset</button>
```

That gets invoked when the "Reset" button is clicked. It pretty much works - when you
click the reset button. the Select box value gets set to "". BUT.. the visual display
of the select box is also set to blank, not "By color".  Why is this the case?

In addition, according to the Chrome DevTools, the selected option is still Green.

Comment: Setting to an array. Try setting to string. -  color_select.val("");

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reset a select element with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10502093/how-to-reset-a-select-element-with-jquery)

Comment: Do't get confused. **Reset** AKA `.reset()` means to Reset a `SELECT` Element to the default (initially) `selected` Option Element attribute. When using `mySel.value = ""` or jQ's `$mySel.val("")` - that's **reassigning**, not *resetting*.

Comment: Sorry, wasn't being that precise... my button is called "reset", it's meant to clear any selected value from the list, not the official ".reset()" function.  What I have is what I need - setting the value to an empty string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the value to an empty string, not an array.

```js
$("#FilterReset").click(function() {
  let color_select = $('select#SelectByColor');
  color_select.val("");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="SelectByColor" class='filter-select' name='color'>
  <option value="">By color</option>
  <option value="Red">Red</option>
  <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
  <option value="Green" selected="selected">Green</option>
  <option value="Yellow">Yellow</option>
</select>

<button id="FilterReset">Reset</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

The value you set for the selector in the `.val(...)` function to needs to match the `value="..."` in HTML. So that should be `color_select.val( "" )`

Here's a code that works and a [codepen](https://codepen.io/kimchouard/pen/qBZMOgL):

```
jQuery($ => {
  $('#FilterReset').on('click', () => {
    $("#SelectByColor").val("");
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, all - my own stupidity, part cut and paste, part not quite getting it... of course, an empty string is the right value to set it to. Works now!