# How do i remove all option from multiselect2side select box?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, multi-select

I used jquery multiselect2side select box. I used below code to add option

```
$("#myselect").multiselect2side('addOption', {name: opionTitle, value: libraryvalue[i].uri, selected: false});
```

In the same way, I want to remove all option from select box. I used below jquery script to remove. But it was not working

```
$("#myselect").empty();
```

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1857781/best-way-to-unselect-a-select-in-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After empty you will need to destroy and again initialize the plugin. Hope this works for you.

```
$('#myselect').empty().multiselect2side('destroy');
$('#myselect').multiselect2side();
```