# Remove element from selected list not from dom

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to have a complicated selection in jQuery
it should be as follows:

```
var ctrls = $('.ctrl').not('.ctrl:disabled,.ctrl:parent:hidden');
ctrls.parents('.InsideContainerControl:hidden').remove();
```

The thing is obviously that the second line actually removes the element from the dom
while what i am looking for is a way to remove it from the selection list

Comment: Can you describe what you mean by `remove it from the selection list`. It's not clear.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to unselect a <select> in jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1857781/best-way-to-unselect-a-select-in-jquery)

Comment: Post the relevant HTML in your question.

Comment: Use .clone() on your initial selection. Though removing the parents doesn't actually affect 'the selected list'.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work, you first filter out the parents, then filter out the children:

```
$('.InsideContainerControl')                   // get all parents
.not('.InsideContainerControl:hidden')         // remove hidden ones
    .find('.ctrl')                             // get all children from the remaining
    .not('.ctrl:disabled,.ctrl:parent:hidden') // remove disabled ones
```

---

Watch this, should ignore 1, 2 (parent hidden) and 4 (disabled):

```js
var sel = 
    $('.InsideContainerControl')                   // get all parents
    .not('.InsideContainerControl:hidden')         // remove hidden ones
        .find('.ctrl')                             // get all children from the remaining
        .not('.ctrl:disabled,.ctrl:parent:hidden');// remove disabled ones

alert(sel.text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="InsideContainerControl" style="display: none">
  <button class="ctrl">1</button>
  <button class="ctrl" disabled>2</button>
</div>
<div class="InsideContainerControl">
  <button class="ctrl">3</button>
  <button class="ctrl" disabled>4</button>
</div>
```